# Recommended (free) software to draw both histogram and graph paper grid

Tags: math-software

Is there any software for drawing both the graph (histogram, ogive or other statistical graphs) and the graph paper grid behind it? I want to draw graph that look like image below.

[image: sample histogram]

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably do this in LibreOffice, a free clone of excel. https://www.libreoffice.org/

Comment: @EthanBolker , can libreoffice produce graph paper grid at the back of the histogram?

Comment: Probably. Perhaps not the small subdivisions. You may need to experiment to get what you want. https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/178137/spreadsheet-how-to-show-gridlines/